# Any country city base domain redirect

Tags: geolocation, ip-geolocation

I have a city based domain and i want to redirect the **cities automatically** from the **ipaddress**. please help me to get a solution for that

Example for India country i have Mumbai.website.com Delhi.website.com etc.i want when people visit to my main website they auto redirect to his city base subdomain. please help me sir.

i try it for country base auto redirect with this code in my .htaccess file, but first i have to install IP2Location Apache Module.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_COUNTRY_SHORT} ^IN$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://indian.dropmyads.com/ [L]
```

but its redirect work for country

i want city base redirect code

Comment: Hi, the link you provided claims to do cities as well as countries. However this website does not provide recommendations of this sort I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry but this site doesn't do recommendations, see the guidelines.

Comment: Make sure you are using the correct database (the one specified by the IP2LocationDBFile param), as each database they offer includes different layers of geographic data (e.g. DB1 only includes country, buy DB3 includes also region and city).

Comment: https://www.maxmind.com/en/free-world-cities-database  i have this data base now how to redirect cities from it? please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use "IP2LOCATION_CITY" for the city name redirection purpose.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:IP2LOCATION_CITY} ^Mumbai$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://indian.dropmyads.com/ [L]
```